# Difference between bracket notation property access and Pick utility in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, interface

I have an interface like below

```js
export type CameraProps = Omit<React.HTMLProps<HTMLVideoElement>, "ref"> & {
    audio?: boolean;
    audioConstraints?: MediaStreamConstraints["audio"];
    mirrored?: boolean;
    screenshotFormat?: "image/webp" | "image/png" | "image/jpeg";
    //between 0 & 1
    screenshotQuality?: number;
    videoConstraints?: MediaStreamConstraints["video"];
    fullScreenRecord?: boolean;
    screenshotDimensions?: ScreenshotDimensions;
    setImageSrc?: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>;
    overlay?: boolean;
}
```

when I use `pick` to pick one of this property like this

```
    private videoConstraints: Pick<CameraProps, 'videoConstraints'>;
```

I get this error in this line of my code

```
        this.videoConstraints = videoConstraints;
```

> Type  boolean | MediaTrackConstraints | undefined  is not assignable to type  Pick<CameraProps, "videoConstraints"> 
> Type  undefined  is not assignable to type  Pick<CameraProps, "videoConstraints">

it seems like `pick` removes `undefined` from the type but when I write the code like below

```
    private videoConstraints: CameraProps['videoConstraints'];
```

every thing is fine

The full code is like below

```js
import React, {Dispatch, SetStateAction} from "react";

export type ScreenshotDimensions = {
    width: number;
    height: number;
}

export type CameraProps = Omit<React.HTMLProps<HTMLVideoElement>, "ref"> & {
    audio?: boolean;
    audioConstraints?: MediaStreamConstraints["audio"];
    mirrored?: boolean;
    screenshotFormat?: "image/webp" | "image/png" | "image/jpeg";
    //between 0 & 1
    screenshotQuality?: number;
    videoConstraints?: MediaStreamConstraints["video"];
    fullScreenRecord?: boolean;
    screenshotDimensions?: ScreenshotDimensions;
    setImageSrc?: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>;
    overlay?: boolean;
}

export type Maybe<T> = NonNullable<T> | undefined;

export type VideoStatus = 'play' | 'error' | 'wait';


class CameraManager {
    private setVideoStatus: Dispatch<SetStateAction<VideoStatus>>;
    private videoRef: MutableRefObject<HTMLVideoElement | null>;
    private audio: Maybe<boolean>;
    private videoConstraints: CameraProps['videoConstraints'];
    private audioConstraints: CameraProps['audioConstraints'];
    private fullScreenRecord: Maybe<boolean>;

    constructor({
                    audio,
                    setVideoStatus,
                    fullScreenRecord,
                    videoConstraints,
                    videoRef,
                    audioConstraints
                }: Pick<CameraProps, 'audio' | 'fullScreenRecord' | 'videoConstraints' | 'audioConstraints'> & {
        setVideoStatus: Dispatch<SetStateAction<VideoStatus>>,
        videoRef: MutableRefObject<HTMLVideoElement | null>
    }) {
        this.setVideoStatus = setVideoStatus;
        this.videoRef = videoRef;
        this.fullScreenRecord = fullScreenRecord;
        this.videoConstraints = videoConstraints;
        this.audioConstraints = audioConstraints;
        this.audio = audio;


        this.requestUserMedia();
    }

    private async requestUserMedia() {
        const portrait = window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)").matches;

        try {
            this.setVideoStatus('play');
            const constraints: MediaStreamConstraints = {
                video: this.fullScreenRecord ? {
                        aspectRatio: portrait ? document.documentElement.clientHeight / document.documentElement.clientWidth : document.documentElement.clientWidth / document.documentElement.clientHeight,
                        ...(typeof this.videoConstraints === 'object' ? this.videoConstraints : undefined),
                    } :
                    typeof this.videoConstraints === 'object' ? {
                        ...this.videoConstraints
                    } : true,
            };

            if (this.audio) {
                constraints.audio = this.audioConstraints || true;
            }
            const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
            if (!this.videoRef.current) {
                return;
            }
            this.videoRef.current.srcObject = stream;
            return stream;
        } catch (e) {
            this.setVideoStatus('error');
            if (e instanceof Error) {
                // Handle specific errors here
            }
            console.log(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your type declaration, you make `videoContraints` optional with the `?`.

[Pick](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) constructs a *new* type from picking keys from another type, so you are essentially telling it to create this type with an optional property:

```
type SomeType = {
    videoConstraints?: MediaStreamConstraints["video"];
}
```

When you assign a property to a different type *which requires* an optional property created by the Pick, it throws an error, whereas using the bracket notation is more lenient.

To use the Pick type, you can use `!` to assert it's defined:

```
this.videoConstraints = videoConstraints!;
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because `Pick` doesn't do what you seem to believe it does. It returns a composite type with properties selected from another type. It doesn't return a type of a single selected property.

See this example ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCuAzRUDeAoKWoEMD8AXFAM7ABOAlgHYDmm2ARoVFfALYMRnoC%2066AegFQAKgAtooSFArE0uZqUq0oAHyjwqAEwiJqELVD5ToIgIxQAvFAAKFAMYBrADxwkiADRQA5Dm8A%20fiFRCSgTGTklaho1DW1dfS10cJEAJitYBGQAbV9vAF0gA)):

```
type Stuff {
    a?: string
    b?: number
}

// The type is { a?: string | undefined }
type T1 = Pick<Stuff, 'a'>

// The type is string | undefined
type T2 = Stuff['a']
```

So

> Pick<CameraProps, 'videoConstraints'>;

evaluates to type

```
{ videoConstraints?: MediaStreamConstraints["video"] }
```

but you already discovered that

```
CameraProps['videoConstraints']
```

is what you actually need. That will evaluate to

```
MediaStreamConstraints["video"] | undefined
```